# How can I avoid the "global $dbh" anti-pattern?

Tags: php, anti-patterns, globals

This is what most of my database-related library code looks like:

*lib.php*

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO(...);

function doSomeDatabaseThing() {
    global $dbh;
    return $dbh->doStuff();
}

function doSomeOtherThing() {
    global $dbh;
    return $dbh->doSomeOtherStuff();
}
```

*index.php*

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once('lib.php');
        echo doSomeDatabaseThing();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I keep reading that globals in PHP are generally bad. Of course, this doesn't mean that I should *never* use globals, but it seems wrong to repeatedly use this pattern in almost all database code I write.

So, how should I do this without globals? I could try something like

*lib.php*

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
function doSomeDatabaseThing($dbh) { ... }
```

*index.php*

```
doSomeDatebaseThing($dbh);
```

but it looks ugly to have to write "`($dbh)`" every single time I call a database function.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: _Dependency Injection_ is beautiful. A hidden dependency inside your function/method is ugly, creepy and frustrating. IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Object-oriented design + Dependency Injection (DI)

You should consider using object-oriented design together with [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) container. I recommend [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) specifically because it has a great [DI container component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html).

Instead of having a bunch of DB-related functions, consider grouping them into classes which deal with particular types of domain objects, like so:

```
// repository interface
interface Repository
{
    public function findById($id);
}

// specific repository dealing with user objects
class UserRepository implements Repository
{
    private $dbh;

    function __construct(PDO $dbh)
    {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        // just an example, should use at least prepared statement here
        $userRow = $this->dbh->query("...");
        // ...
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Instead of having `global $dbh` you now **inject** it into constructor of `SomethingRepository` as a **dependency**, hence the name of the pattern. That is called constructor injection, and there are [other types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Three_types_of_dependency_injection).

Injection is basically instantiating all the dependencies and passing them into constructors/setters. That's what DI containers do. You provide a configuration describing how objects depend on each other, framework builds them.

### Why is `global $x` considered anti-pattern?

1. Name of `$x` can be a subject to change => happy time renaming
2. Any object using `$x` can overwrite it => happy time debugging
3. Can cause security issues in case you have [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.register-globals) enabled or if you including third-party source files => happy time dealing with hacker attacks

> Of course, this doesn't mean that I should never use globals

That means you should avoid using `global $x` construct at all costs. You can totally build any application without it, unless you stuck with some legacy code or prehistoric version of PHP.